# Calculate difference month until current month with bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some problems, I want to calculate difference month until current month and I only have 1 table:

month_of_booking

| Name | MoB |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | 2020-12-01 |
| bbb | 2021-02-01 |

Current month is 2020-04-01

My expected result is this:

month_of_booking

| Name | MoB | month | dated_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 2020-12-01 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| aaaa | 2020-12-01 | 2021-02-01 | 2 |
| aaaa | 2020-12-01 | 2021-03-01 | 3 |
| aaaa | 2020-12-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 |
| bbb | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | 1 |
| bbb | 2021-02-01 | 2021-04-01 | 2 |

I want to create view table so it would be generate automatic when current month is moving

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `generate_date_array()` and `unnest()`:

```
select t.name, mon
from t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(mob, date_trunc(current_date, month)) mon
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [generate_date_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array):

```
with month_of_booking as (
  select 'aaaa' as name, Date '2020-12-01' as mob union all
  select 'bbb', Date '2021-02-01'
)
select *, DATE_DIFF(month, mob, MONTH) as dated_diff
from month_of_booking, unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_ADD(mob, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as month
```

[image]